# crossfilter: obtain the count of values falling into the product of two columns

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a data set like

```
  {"parent":"/home","inside":"/files","filename":"type.jar",
   "extension":"jar","type":"modified","archive"}
```

Likewise many there are many rows in the json array. I am using crossfilter to read the data and plot graphs and datatables. the Type in the data set has values "added", "modified" and "deleted".

I want to create a data table like

---

### Extension | Added | Modified | Deleted

where added, modified and deleted will hold the count of the files with the specific extension. Can anyone suggest me a way to do so?

So far I have created a dimension like this:

```
var extensionType = facts.dimension(function(d) { 
        return d.extension; });
var extensionTypeGroup=extensionType.group();
```

and I get a grouped output like this,

```
{"key":"class","value":424},
{"key":"js","value":176},
{"key":"properties","value":26},
{"key":"jar","value":10},
{"key":"css","value":8},
{"key":"txt","value":6},
{"key":"war","value":4},
{"key":"png","value":4},
{"key":"handlebars","value":4}, 
{"key":"jar_local","value":2},
{"key":"aar","value":2}
```

How do I get the separate count of added deleted and modified?

Comment: Have you tried by creating a group `dimension.group([groupValue])` and then take the `group.size()`

Comment: i have grouped the values based on the extension type. which i am getting the total value of added, modified and deleted summed up. I need the separate count of added modified and deleted for each extension type .

Comment: Refer this [http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/](http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/)

Comment: Hi, please use the dc.js tag for questions about the charting library - dc is quite something else.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to reduce to an object rather than a single value.

This is covered in the FAQ: [How do I reduce multiple values at once? What if rows contain a single value but a different value per row?](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#what-if-rows-contain-a-single-value-but-a-different-value-per-row) You probably just needed the right search terms to find it.

Actually it looks like the code from the FAQ will work for you unmodified:

```
var extensionTypeGroup = extensionType.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) + v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        p[v.type] -= v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function() { // initial
        return {};
    });
```